# Loop to check condition

Tags: vba, excel

I need to check at every cells change a certain condition, I wrote this one, but it doesn't work, what's wrong?

In every sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 ColoraLabel.ColoraLabel (ActiveSheet.Name) 
End sub
```

In the module I've written:

```
Public Function ColoraLabel(nomeFoglio)

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Set Foglio = Sheets(nomeFoglio)
Set Target = Foglio.Range("f21")
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
     For I = 1 To WS_Count
        MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name
        Set Foglio = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name
        Set Target = Foglio.Range("f21")

        If Target = "1" Then
            Foglio.Tab.ColorIndex = 4
        Else
             Foglio.Tab.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
     Next I
End Function
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Where does the code fail? What error code are you getting?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: If I'm guessing right, are you trying to "know" if the cell color changed?

Comment: @chuck22  see my answer below, you have 2 versions you can test and see if they fit your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code below in the `Workbook_SheetChange` event, instead os putting the same piece of code in every worksheet (especialy that you need the same code for all your worksheets).

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Sht As Worksheet, Foglio As Worksheet
Dim TargetRng As Range

For Each Sht In Worksheets
    MsgBox Sht.Name

    Set Foglio = Sheets(Sht.Name)
    Set TargetRng = Foglio.Range("F21")

    If TargetRng = "1" Then
        Foglio.Tab.ColorIndex = 4
    Else
        Foglio.Tab.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If

Next Sht

End Sub
```

---

However, since your code checks the value in cell "F21" and changes the `Sheet.tab` color according to the value found in `Range("F21")`, you can run the minimized and cleaner code version below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

' why scan all cells, if the only thing your function checks is the value of "F21"
If Not Intersect(Range("F21"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If Target = "1" Then
        Sh.Tab.ColorIndex = 4
    Else
        Sh.Tab.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If

End If

End Sub
```